# Fire Laravel Model Event for each row in Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a [model event](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) for the `updating` method for my model.

```
Hotel::updating(function($hotel) {
    // Update cache
    $hotel->q = $hotel->country->name . " " . $hotel->destination->name;
});
```

This works great, if I save() a single object using eloquent.

However I want to write an artisan task, to update that field for **each** row in the table. How I can trigger the model event for each row in a table?

I tried using something like `Event::fire('eloquent.updating', function(Hotel::self);`, since model events are based on regular events. However this throws me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that models do fire an `eloquent.updating` event. However to allow the event dispatcher to fire the event for the correct models, the model name is appended to the event namespace. This is the code that is used to fire model events:

```
protected function fireModelEvent($event, $halt = true)
{
    if ( ! isset(static::$dispatcher)) return true;

    // We will append the names of the class to the event to distinguish it from
    // other model events that are fired, allowing us to listen on each model
    // event set individually instead of catching event for all the models.
    $event = "eloquent.{$event}: ".get_class($this);

    $method = $halt ? 'until' : 'fire';

    return static::$dispatcher->$method($event, $this);
}
```

Your model event will actually be : `eloquent.updating: Hotel`. This would naturally mean that the model is listening using that same syntax.

Just out of curiosity, why do you need to fire the event manually? You can use the models themselves in an artisan task that would fire them for you.