# How to fire an update event when updating one to one relationships in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two entities:

1. Person
2. Employee

Person hasOne Employee. Employee belongsTo Person.

Generally speaking, my task is: when person data changes, I need to make a copy of the model in revisions table. Each Person also hasMany PersonRevision. Kind of log of updating persons, which is used in many places in our application.

Technically, I separated Person and Employee, because not every person is employee and employee has a lot of additional columns.

So, the question is: when I update Person and do not touch its attributes but update the employee (which belongs to the person) attributes, the Update event does not fire in PersonObserver. 
And that's true since Person attributes has not been changed.

But

1. I consider Employee as a part of Person, separated one to one in order to keep persons (which are not employees) table clean
2. Every time person attributes or its employee attributes updated I need to create 2 revisions: person & employee. For this purpose I want to use Event Observers

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way for you in this situation is to create a listener for `employee.updated` event and trigger `person.updated` event inside it. So each time an `Employee` is updated, it automatically triggers `Person` update. You can then go further and check which fields are updated, and if those are only fields related to `Employee` and none related to `Person`, then NOT trigger the person.update event.

Here's a small [Laravel model events tutorial](https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-create-events-for-created-updated-deleted-model-task-in-laravel-5) in case you need some guidelines.

Comment: Well, the thing is even if only employee data is updated, it means that person is "updated" as well. Because employee belongs to person. Another example: imagine we have Person and Passport. 1 person 1 passport. If passport is updated it means that person is updated. I can merge passport & person into one table though but here employee and person is separated to keep person table clean. 
I'll check your link, got your idea. 

Also thank you for supporting lichess :)

Comment: Triggering `person.updated` event in the `employee.updated` event-listener should do the trick. You can use `event()` helper function as per docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#dispatching-events . See you at the chessboard! :)

Comment: Not sure I get it. We're talking about custom events, not eloquent ones (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937643/fire-laravel-model-event-for-each-row-in-table) right? So instead of using model observers, we use our own events (person.updated, employee.updated), and do the revision-stuff here, in event handlers, right? There might be caveat: if user updates both person & employee data, it will work like this: create person&employee revision after person updating, create person&employee revision after employee updating and there might be also a loop. Hmm..

Comment: I don't think observers would do it here. You should go with EventListeners. Then you could do it via custom events, for instance Then both Person::update and Employee::update would trigger the same event (`MyCustomUserUpdateEvent`). Or you can just imitate the events that Eloquent already generates. The model events have names like `model.updated` and `model.created`, so if you generate such an event manually from a different place, the event-listener on the model will catch it.